# How can I get stack overflow software powering my private Q&A site?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed another site with a question answer section that appears to be powered by the same software that powers stack overflow. How can I get or license the software that powers stack overflow for use on a private site?

Comment: This is the second question of this type I've seen today. Has no one heard of stackexchange.com?

Comment: @AustinMullins If I said this for every question tagged `C`, I could ask "Has no C programmer ever heard of pointers?"...

Comment: @H2CO3 true that. The difference is there's a link to StackExchange on every single page of this site, at least three of which you have to load on the way to asking this question.